# Number of elements returned by find in bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

test=$(find . -name "*.cfg")
echo ${#test[@]}
```

And the output is simply 1. However, find returns 8 elements and when used in a loop their names are displayed correctly:

```
for f in $(find . -name "*.cfg")
do
    echo $f
done
```

How can I check the size of the `test` array? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only safe way to store the output of `find` into an array is to use the `-print0` extension, which is not POSIX (yet, GNU `find` supports it):

```
files=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    files+=( "$file" )
done < <(
    find . -name '*.cfg' -print0
)
printf 'There are %d files found.\n' "${#files[@]}"
```

---

If you only want the number of files found, you can use this (using `-printf`, not POSIX but supported by GNU):

```
xfiles=$(find . -name '*.cfg' -printf 'x')
printf 'There are %d files found.\n' "${#xfiles}"
```

or in a POSIX-compliant way:

```
xfiles=$(find . -name '*.cfg' -exec printf "%.sx" {} +)
printf 'There are %d files found.\n' "${#xfiles}"
```

---

Now Bash≥4 can deal with this on its own:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
files=( **/*.cfg )
printf 'There are %d files found.\n' "${#files[@]}"
```

(though it might be slower than `find`).

Comment: For the first options, does that mean I have to call `find` twice if want to loop over its elements?

Comment: @JaviV: no, the found files are stored in the array `files`. To loop on them: `for file in "${files[@]}"; do echo "$file"; done`. Same for the Bash solutions: the elements are stored in the array `files`.

Comment: Sorry I meant for the second/third option: `xfiles=$(find . -name '*.cfg' -exec printf "%.sx" {} +)

Comment: @JaviV if you want to loop, don't use the 2nd and 3rd solutions: with these solutions you'd have to call `find` a second time.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that `print0` was not POSIX but, it turns out, [neither is `printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)! Which means it might not even be possible to do this POSIXly.

Comment: @terdon: You overlooked my answer: there's a solution with the `-printf` switch of `find` that I specified is not POSIX, and there's a solution with the _command_ `printf`, which is part of the [POSIX utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/utilities/printf.html). So yes, it's possible to do this POSIXly.

Comment: Ah! Yes, indeed, sorry. I missed the `-exec` and thought you were running `-printf` which as I was surprised to find is also not POSIX. Well, I would upvote you but I'm afraid I already had :)

Answer (score 2):

`test` is a string (not an array).

You are using `[@]` on it which isn't doing anything useful and is breaking things for you. Drop it.

You want `${#test}` to get the length of the string. If you want an array you need to do that differently.

You **do not** want to parse/read/`for`-loop/etc. over the output of find that way though (it isn't safe for "odd" file names).

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for ways to do that safely (specifically see the section about `-print0`).

Comment: Although I appreciate your answer, it does not solve my problem. I am newbie with bash (I find it weirdly complicated). By the way, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @JaviV: I'd really appreciated if you tried following through with Etan's instructions -- that will a) get you out of your newbie status and b) this solution is the only sane one: pointing you to your mistakes, pointing you to a set of good practices.

Comment: Both chepner and gniourf_gniourf have added answers that contain actual runnable code for this task. The first few details here about some of the other errors in the original are still useful information though.

Answer (score 2):

Since you aren't using any other feature of `find`, I would use a glob to create the array instead:

```
# Bash 4+
shopt -s globstar
test=( **/*.cfg )
```

The `globstar` option enables the pattern `**`, which matches 0 or more directories in a path. It allows for recursive matching with a directory hierarchy, so `**/*.cfg` would match `./foo.cfg`, `./bar/hello world.cfg`, etc. Each matched file, regardless of whatever special characters may exist in the file name, will be treated as a single array entry.

If you need to support an older version of `bash`, there are more complicated techniques you can use assuming your version of `find` supports `-print0` or something similar.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit what your code actually does? It works but I cannot understand it.

Comment: Thank you. What should I do then if I want only one specific folder (and not subfolders)?

Comment: I wrote `test=( $1**/*.cfg )` where $1 is the relative path to the folder I want and it seems to work. Is there any problem with this solution?

Comment: I don't think so, but to be safe I'd write `test=("$1"/**/*.cfg)`; the quotes will make a difference if `$1` contains whitespace, and the extra `/` if `$1` already ends with `/` won't hurt.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create an array first, try this:

```
test=($(find . -name "*.cfg"))
echo ${#test[@]}
```

Comment: what behaviour does that show when file names contain newlines and spaces?

Comment: @MarcusMüller you may also add glob characters into the list… this is a very bad answer! it shows broken code and bad practices.

Comment: But so far it works for me. I will appreciate any better answers.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf  I forgot to mention you in the previous comment and is late to edit it :)

Comment: @JaviV: the better answer is the one given by Etan, Imho

Comment: @MarcusMüller "If you want an array you need to do that differently." That is not enough. Although the link is nice, a small summary is preferred so that the questions is already answered at any point.

Comment: @JaviV: it is. there's plenty of documentation out there. You obviously want to program something, so you will need to learn the ways of the programmer -ie. how to read manuals and documentation.